# I'm creating a maven project and I'm a beginner..I got this error. can help to resolve this is my pom.xml & web.xml

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.project
    Online_Medical_Reporting_System
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Online_Medical_Reporting_System Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            junit
            junit
            3.8.1
            test
        
        
            org.hibernate.javax.persistence
            hibernate-jpa-2.1-api
            1.0.0.Final
        
        
        
            org.hibernate
            hibernate-validator
            4.0.2.GA
        
        
            org.hibernate
            hibernate-core
            3.3.2.GA
        
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-aop
            4.1.6.RELEASE

```
    <!-- The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains 
        Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation 
        for web applications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features 
        such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the 
        IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>Online_Medical_Reporting_System</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

> > Blockquote

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    Online_Medical_Reporting_System

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: And what makes you think `org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider` is on your classpath?

Comment: What have you done that led to this output? Your statement that you're creating something should also contain the steps you've taken, including any relevant code or commands you've used.

Comment: Post your POM. Assuming dependenceis have been setup wrong.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I've posted pom.xml & web.xml

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1):

You're mixing versions of spring dependencies which you should never do unless you have an exceptional reason.

Please see this blog post that details how to and why you shouldn't do this, it's spring boot releated but the idea is the exact same https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

Quick example shown here, http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom

```
<dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features 
    such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the 
    IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependencies are controlled through the BOM Import. Additionally I believe a lot of what you have defined would be transitively pulled e.g. shouldn't need to define `context`, `beans` etc. I'd check your dependency hierarchy and flatten the defined dependencies.

Comment: Why the down vote? Also missed the other dependencies due to formatting but you get the idea.